# efficiently keeping a collection of the last N pushed items

Tags: arrays, go, memory, slice

Given:

1. slice with pre-known capacity
2. capacity and number of slices are large , and around 15MB of memory will be used, so I don't want to waste memory and want to keep minimum memory.
3. slice will be updated by removing first element and adding new element to end of slice.

`b = append(b[1:], n)` will increase capacity

to shift and assign myself, I wrote

```
func shiftAndPut(a []int, n int) (b []int) {
    b = make([]int, cap(a), cap(a))
    for i,v := range(a[1:]) {
        b[i] = v
    }
    b[len(b)-1] = n
    return
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7xIBh0UPp2w

It keeps the capacity same, but requires various computations

1. iterating slice one time,
2. calling of function,
3. new variable for small time,
4. sub slicing in range function, which adds more computations,
5. etc

Is there any more optimised way to do this?

Comment: In oder to shift values in a slice (or array), you need to move each value, there's no "more optimized" way to do this. It sounds like you want a different data structure, are you trying to make a ring-buffer?

Comment: The temporary buffer can be eliminated: https://play.golang.org/p/72T8AquHG-B.   If the cost of shifting is high, then you may want to use a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) as JimB suggests.

Comment: @JimB Wouldn't a double ended queue do the same? Like he gets the data from one end and add to the other

Comment: yeah no need for temporary buffer (thanks) , my problem is like I will always have n data in order , and whenever new data comes, I need to throw the first one and keep the new one in last

Comment: @MikaelBrenner: sure, I only mentioned one other possibility for brevity, since a ring-buffer is often the most efficient implementation, and the question was really about slices.

Comment: @mkmayank: if you are always removing from the head and appending to the tail with a fixed amount of storage, then you want a circular buffer of some sort. There is a [`container/ring`](https://golang.org/pkg/container/ring) package in the stdlib, or you can simply abstract the concept over a fixed slice (or find another package that does for you)

Comment: using ring buffer, I just need to keep track of pointer(read,write) , in my case it will always be the same  https://play.golang.org/p/_4Of9XTUsQA is it almost optimized or is there still room ?

Comment: @JimB thanks for suggesting `ring` package , though it will consume function stack, type assertion, internal computation, Which will be better, above commented custom pointer solution or ring package in terms of performance, as this operation will happen at every millisecond multiple times ?

Comment: Obviously doing less work is faster. If you can pre-allocate what you need, and only manipulate the slice index, then there's not much else to optimize. When in doubt, benchmark and measure.

Comment: thanks, I will post do benchmark and post here too, if someone requires in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice ring buffer, custom implementation :

```
data := make([]int, cap, cap)
pointer := 0

data[pointer] = newData
pointer = (pointer+1) % cap
```

[container/ring](https://golang.org/pkg/container/ring) package implemetation :

```
data := ring.New(cap)
data.Value = newData
data = data.Next()
```

After suggestion in comment thread, I did [benchmark](https://play.golang.org/p/KrVJodjDGy7) between [slice custom shifting](https://play.golang.org/p/_4Of9XTUsQA) and [container/ring](https://golang.org/pkg/container/ring)

```
BenchmarkCustom1000-4         100000         17322 ns/op
BenchmarkRing1000-4           100000         22824 ns/op
BenchmarkCustom-4           100000000           17.4 ns/op
BenchmarkRing-4             100000000           22.8 ns/op
```

custom slice shifting using variable (pointer or flag) is faster and also memory optimised.